# Custom ActionBar is not displaying icons

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, appbar

I have done each and everything mentioned in the documentation on https://developer.android.com/training/appbar.

This is onCreate method

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.get_location_btn);
    saveLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    longText = findViewById(R.id.long_text);
    latText = findViewById(R.id.lat_text);
    attractionNameText = findViewById(R.id.location_name_text);
    ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    detailsText = findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    getViewSavedLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.view_saved_location_btn);
    attractionTypeText = findViewById(R.id.attractionTypeText);
    updateToFirebaseBtn = findViewById(R.id.update_to_firebase);
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "app_database")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();
    getViewSavedLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    updateToFirebaseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


   toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Here is the app_bar xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the main_manu.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/enter_attraction"
        android:icon="@drawable/upload_icon"
        android:title="@string/upload_icon_title"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

Output on the emulator

[image]

Comment: There is not the part where you inflate the menu.

Comment: Can you plz provide me a link to do so. I am beginner in android.

Comment: Look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021600/how-do-i-inflate-an-android-options-menu-and-set-an-item-to-enabled-false, and here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807538/android-inflate-menu-add-items-to-action-bar-only-on-click-of-a-button . When you have a problem like that, the solution may be in StackOverflow, you should look before other questions, and other answers, the official documentation should not be your only resource, I hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It got fixed.

Comment: If you managed to fix it and it works for you, upload and publish your code for future needy people.

Answer (score 0):

In activity add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

in fragment add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreate

This issue has been resolved